# Naming convention for an abstract class?

Tags: c++

I know that the naming convention for an interface is something like `IName`. But what if I am creating an abstract class?

Should I also write an I in front of the class name?

Comment: It sounds a bit confuse for me. What do you mean by abstract and interface? In C++ a class is abstract if it has at least one pure virtual function. An interface class is usually such a - typically, but not necessarily abstract - class, that is primarily for hiding implementation details in derived classes and being used on public interfaces.

Comment: The `I` prefix is a Microsoftism (for COM and .NET), not a C++ naming convention per se.

Comment: In java and c# you can see directly if the class is abstract or if it is an interface. I already saw several times the I prefix so I adapted it. I just want to make it clear to other developers that this class is abstract or and interface. I probably use the I prefix for abstract classes too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As opposed to Oracles Java coding conventions, there is no "The" naming convention for C++.

- If you are working on a project for some company you should follow their naming conventions. If there are no documented conventions - look around the code base and try to follow the swarm, consistency is the key.
- If you are starting something on your own, many find [google's c++ coding conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html) as a good start.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know *any* C++ developers who think Google's conventions are good general guidelines. They're great for Google, but they have to work within constraints that are not universally applicable.

Comment: I wrote that it was a good start, not the holy grail. Are there any good conventions that are _universally_ applicable? Feel free to link to other guidelines.

Comment: That's precisely the point: I and many others do not think it *is* a good start. It contains a lot of bad, inapplicable, and misleading advice.

Comment: Feel free to link to other guidelines. I am curious.

Comment: Dead link to Google's coding conventions. Closest match alive today: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Naming

Comment: I think "C++ Core Guidelines"  is a good start these days: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to adhere to a specific naming convention, please name it. As the other answer explains, there is no global "C++ Rule" regarding naming conventions.

If you are using Hungarian notation, I believe that the convention is indeed to prefix 'I' as you did for 'IName'.

**Note:** *Whilst there is no "interface" as such in C++, you can define classes with only pure virtual methods and no member variables.*

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a global naming convention. At the time you know by what naming convention, you can look up the answer in it.